# C++: Can I use this safely in a destructor?

Tags: c++, this, destructor

Todays' question is: Can I use `this` in a destructor, and if yes what are the restrictions I must obey to... For example, I know I'm not supposed to do anything with base classes, since they are gone. But what other restrictions apply? And can I safely assume that the `this` (as a pointer... ie. memory address... a number) is the same as in the constructor?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Usage of "this" in destructor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10979250/usage-of-this-in-destructor)

Answer (score 7):

> Can I use `this` in a destructor

Yes.

> For example, I know I'm not supposed to do anything with base classes, since they are gone.

No, the base classes are still intact at this point. Members (and perhaps other base classes) of *derived* classes have already been destroyed, but members and base classes of this class remain until after the destructor has finished.

> But what other restrictions apply?

Virtual functions are dispatched according to the class currently being destroyed, not the former most-derived class. So be careful calling them, and in particular don't call any functions that are pure virtual in this class.

Don't cast `this` to a derived type, since it is no longer a valid object of that type.

You can't `delete this` from the destructor, for obvious reasons.

> And can I safely assume that the this (as a pointer... ie. memory address... a number) is the same as in the constructor?

Yes, an object's address remains the same from before its constructor runs until after its destructor runs.

Answer (score 4):

As [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10979250/usage-of-this-in-destructor?rq=1) it's perfectly valid.

You should avoid [calling virtual functions](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/nevercall.html), though.

Answer (score 3):

Base classes are *not* gone in the destructor, you can use them normally.

Derived class *are* gone, so in particular virtual calls will not reach derived classes.

`this` has the same value as in the constructor and everywhere else in the class.

The main restriction is that you should not allow any exception to leave the destructor. This means that you have no means of indicating failure[*]. Generally you should only perform operations that are certain to succeed (such as freeing resources owned by the object): anything you do that can fail, it must be OK to ignore the failure. Anything you do that can throw, you should catch the exception. Hopefully you have fully documented the possible exceptions thrown by all the functions of `this`, so you know whether or not the things you want to do with `this` can throw.

[*] well, you could build a mechanism for the destructor to record somewhere 
what happened, but users of the class would have to actively check it. This is unlikely to result in a pleasant user experience.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problem using `this` in the destructor. At this time, the object is still there. The destructor is for you to free existing resources before the object is destroyed.

But avoid calling virtual functions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use it normally. You have the object there.

Answer (score 1):

Destructor is a method, which is called *before* your object is physically destroyed, such that you can deinitialize it properly. In order to do so, you *must* have access to its fields, so you can safely access them by the *this* keyword.

The order of destructors is reverse to the constructors, so when your destructor runs, destructors of base classes haven't run yet - you should have access to all their fields. On the other hand, destructors of derived classes have already run, so - for example - [calling virtual or abstract methods](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/calling-virtuals-from-dtors.html) may result in undefined behavior.

Additionally, keep in mind, that it's very dangerous to [throw exceptions in destructors](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/dtors-shouldnt-throw.html). If you do so, you risk terminating your application.

Answer (score 1):

Since objects are destructed from the most derived class down to the base, derived classes destructors will already have executed. So you must make sure not to call methods overridden in derived classes on `this`. Apart from that, it's fine.