# Does std::unique_ptr set its underlying pointer to nullptr inside its destructor?

Tags: c++, unique-ptr, nullptr

When implementing my own `unique_ptr`( just for fun), I found it cannot pass this [test file](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/testsuite/20_util/unique_ptr/54351.cc) from `libstdcxx`:

```
struct A;

struct B
{
  std::unique_ptr<A> a;
};

struct A
{
  B* b;
  ~A() { VERIFY(b->a != nullptr); }
};

void test01()
{
  B b;
  b.a.reset(new A);
  b.a->b = &b;
}
```

[gcc passes](https://wandbox.org/permlink/AJdrekyCC9dN7qPF) this test file happily (of course, this file is from libstdcxx), while [clang fails](https://wandbox.org/permlink/diZDhiT74aG96zgW) for the `VERIFY` part.

Question:

1. Is it implementation dependent or undefined behavior?
2. I guess this postcondition (`b->a != nullptr`) is important for gcc, otherwise it'll not have a test file for it, but I don't know what's behind it. Is it related to optimization? I know many UB are for better optimizations.

Comment: It would be nice to see your `unique_ptr` implementation for reference (at least the destructor).

Comment: @user673679 I think the behavior OP is talking about is from the standard `unique_ptr` (see the Wandbox links).

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce this behavior anywhere. It passes on [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5bde6d7886995dc2).

Comment: Yes, the question is about std::unique_ptr, not my own one

Comment: @MárioFeroldi `clang` on coliru uses libstdc++ from GCC. Add `-stdlib=libc++` and you will get an assertion failure.

Comment: It seems [libc++ clears the pointer](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/272871b658429a2da4c28ddecbfbe7574f781a7f/include/memory#L2606)? The standard doesn't seem to say anything about it [here](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/unique.ptr#single.dtor).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`clang` (libc++) seems to be non-compliant on this point because the standard says:

> [[unique.ptr.single.dtor]](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/unique.ptr.single.dtor)
>
> ```
> ~unique_ptr();
> ```
>
> 1. *Requires:* The expression `get_­deleter()(get())` shall be well-formed, shall have well-defined behavior, and shall not throw exceptions.
>      [ *Note:* The use of `default_­delete` requires `T` to be a complete type.
>      — *end note*
>       ]
> 2. Effects: If `get() == nullptr` there are no effects.
>      Otherwise `get_­deleter()(get())`.

So the destructor should be equivalent to `get_deleter()(get())`, which would imply that `b->a` cannot be `nullptr` within the destructor of `A` (which is called inside `get_deleter()` by the `delete` instruction).

---

On a side note, both `clang` (libc++) and `gcc` (libstdc++) sets the pointer to `nullptr` when destroying a `std::unique_ptr`, but here is `gcc` destructor:

```
auto& __ptr = _M_t._M_ptr();
if (__ptr != nullptr)
    get_deleter()(__ptr);
__ptr = pointer();
```

...and here is `clang` (call to `reset()`):

```
pointer __tmp = __ptr_.first();
__ptr_.first() = pointer();
if (__tmp)
   __ptr_.second()(__tmp);
```

As you can see, `gcc` first deletes then assigns to `nullptr` (`pointer()`) while `clang` first assigns to `nullptr` (`pointer()`) then delete<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup> `pointer` is an alias corresponding to `Deleter::pointer`, if it exists, or simply `T*`.

Comment: off-topic: `pointer` just defaults to `Deleter::pointer` or falls back to `T *` otherwise.

Comment: @user673679 I think you're right. The standard does not specify the post-condition but the behaviour between `get_deleter()(get())` and `clang`'s behavior is inconsistent. I'll update the answer.

Comment: The VERIFY function tries to access an instance of a unique_ptr after the destructor of the unique_ptr has been started. Isn't that undefined behavior?

Comment: @Handy999 This is not UB (AFAIK), you can call member functions (careful with virtual functions) and access members of an object being destroyed. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10979250/usage-of-this-in-destructor.

Comment: I have to return to the topic. From N4659:

>>20.5.4.10  Library object access
2 If an object of a standard library type is accessed, and the beginning of the object’s lifetime (6.8) does not happen before the access, or the access does not happen before the end of the object’s lifetime, the behavior is undefined unless otherwise specified.<<

and

>>6.8  Object lifetime
(1.2) ...  The lifetime of an object of type T ends when: ... T is a class type with a non-trivial destructor (15.4), the destructor call starts,<<

Comment: @Handy999 http://www.eel.is/c++draft/class.cdtor#4 says that member functions can be called during destruction, and http://www.eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#4 indicates that rules for accessing object within lifetime and within construction/destruction are differents. Related questions I found on SO (including the one I linked previously) seems to say this is well-defined. Still, I agree that your quote may indicate otherwise... I am not expert enough regarding the standard to add more to this.

Comment: Again, thanks for the answer. I am still not sure since one has to distinguish between the language requirements and the library requirements. You can certainly access member functions of your own classes during construction/destruction. But I am still not sure what the guarantees are for library classes.

Answer (score 4):

Both libstdc++ and libc++ are conforming because this is unobservable by a well-defined program. During the destructor's execution, [[res.on.objects]/2](https://wg21.link/res.on.objects#2) prohibits any attempt to observe (or modify, for that matter) the state of the `unique_ptr` on pain of undefined behavior:

> If an object of a standard library type is accessed, and the beginning of the object's lifetime does not happen before the access, or the access does not happen before the end of the object's lifetime, the behavior is undefined unless otherwise specified.

In fact, `unique_ptr`'s destructor *is* why this paragraph was added in the first place (by [LWG2224](https://wg21.link/LWG2224)).

Additionally, after the destruction is complete, the contents of the storage it occupies is indeterminate by [[basic.life]/4](https://wg21.link/basic.life#4):

> The properties ascribed to objects and references throughout this document apply for a given object or reference only during its lifetime.

Answer (score 0):

There is no requirement on the final state of the memory occupied by the `std::unique_ptr<>` after destruction. It wouldn't make sense to set it to null as the memory is being returned to where ever it was allocated from. GCC probably checks that its not null to make sure nobody added unnecessary code to clear it. Under the right circumstances, forcing a clear of the value when not needed could cause a performance hit.